# Is it possible to convert an aspx page to amp version (Accelerated Mobile Pages)?

Tags: c#, amp-html

As till now I have seen only static content or any simple html page can converted to amp version.

Comment: This might be helpful: [Creating Google AMP Pages With ASP.NET MVC](http://www.danylkoweb.com/Blog/creating-google-amp-pages-with-aspnet-mvc-E7)

Comment: As view part is divided in MVC, so it is useful in that case, in my project code and view part is mixed so how it can be done? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0):

This may be way to late for you but the sites we run are ASP.NET Web forms written in C#. In order to convert or show the end user an AMP version of our content, we had to write some C# code.

We retrieved our content and stripped out HTML, script tags, MS Word code(!). In addition we added AMP specific tags where the AMP specification told us to. For example converting `<image>` to `<amp-img>`, etc.

It is possible but it isn't a quick fix as the code for an AMP page is different to HTML pages rendered on the desktop.

The other thing to remember is that your rendered AMP page must be [valid](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/preview_and_validate) otherwise it will not be cached by Google and displayed in search results.

The [AMP Project](https://www.ampproject.org/) site is great as a resource about the spec but little on conversion from one code base to another. The other thing I found useful was the [AMP YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXPBsjgKKG2HqsKBhWA4uQw) channel as it had real examples where publishers like [The Guardian](https://youtu.be/T-RplasFnb0) explained their approach to converting their content.